# Does it matter for runtime performance if a method is called by its explicit type?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I am currently writing an application that creates Java byte code and also writes method calls. Until now, the module writing this byte code does not have information on the actual type of the instance a method call is invoked on but it does know the type for which a particular method was defined for. For example:

```
class Foo {   
  public void foo() { } 
}

class Bar extends Foo {   
  public void bar() { } 
}
```

the current version of the engine would execute

```
INVOKEVIRTUAL Foo.foo
```

even on objects of type `Bar` because it knows that `foo` was defined in `Foo`. This is legal in the JVM (of course) but the Java compiler would translate it to

```
INVOKEVIRTUAL Bar.foo
```

when it was "normal" Java source code. I am currently wondering if the JVM actually uses the information of the explicit subtype or if this is ignored / optimized when the class is loaded. I was wondering since the verifier is figuring out the actual type anyways and will not let me write illegal method calls and I wonder why the runtime would not make use of this information when it already is available. I am in particularly wondering if it has a performance impact when super types are interfaces (`INVOKEINTERFACE`) where the virtual method table cannot be used if the JVM would not figure out the actual type.

I can of course extend my module but I would need to provide additional information to it which would bloat my code and which I do not want to do if it did not have an effect. So I ask: Does the type effect performance or does the JVM take care of this explicit resolution?

Comment: +1 This is the best question I've read this year on SO. Can you measure your use cases? I think you can find the answers on your own, but I guess someone with more knowledge will be able to explain if there are any differences and why.

Comment: By `invokedynamic` you actually mean `invokevirtual`.

Comment: I don't think `invokespecial` is allowed even on `final` methods. The code must not severely break if the target class is recompiled without `final` and a subclass overrides the method. Only `private` methods are allowed to be `invokespecial`d.

Comment: @Marko - actually invokespecial is used for three things - constructor calls, private method calls, and superclass calls. In the later case it will actually check for overrides if the ACC_SUPER flag is set. At any rate, it can be used on final methods just fine.

Comment: @Antimony Of those you mention only `private` methods are relevant.

Comment: @Marko Why would it be emitted for a public method call? Like I said, it's used for constructor calls, private method calls, and superclass method calls.

Comment: @Marko You are right, I just looked at the byte code compiled with javac and it does use `INVOKEVIRTUAL` for `final` methods. I used `INVOKESPECIAL` in my application so far and the JVM does not complain. I will however change this to imitate javac. Zou are, of course, also right about that `INVOKEDYNAMIC` should be `INVOKEVIRTUAL`.

Comment: @Antimony So apparently this is just a misunderstanding. The intended meaning of my words is, `invokespecial` must not be applied to regular method calls, even if they are `final`.

Comment: I assume `INVOKEVIRTUAL Foo.bar` is a typo, and should have read `INVOKEVIRTUAL Foo.foo`, as `bar()` is not defined on `Foo`.  Same goes for the instruction that follows it.

Comment: @Marko That's not quite true either. You can apply it to regular method calls if you really want to. It's just that it has different behavior than invokevirtual and it's rarely the behavior you want.

Comment: method `Foo.bar` does not exists, so `invokevirtual Foo.bar` should cause a verification error when the class with such instruction is loaded.

Comment: @MikeStrobel You are of course right. I hope it was still clear from the context, I went blind for `foo` and `bar` over the years.

Comment: @Antimony Even if that is not prevented by the verifier, that fact isn't very relevant because it would be a violation of the purpose of `invokespecial`, which is clearly specified as "special handling for superclass, private, and instance initialization method invocations".

Comment: @Antimony Nope, the verifier does not allow it, so you are positively wrong: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad invokespecial instruction: current class isn't assignable to reference class.`

Comment: @Marko Ah, I didn't bother testing it. I guess the verifier is stricter than described in the specification, not that that's a surprise.

Comment: @Antimony It is [as strict as the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9.2): "Each invokespecial instruction must name an instance initialization method (§2.9), a method in the current class, or a method in a superclass of the current class."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None of the distinctions in the bytecode will matter much for performance of JIT-compiled code.

HotSpot will routinely keep a type profile for each `invokevirtual` call site. If the record indicates only one type being dispatched on, the JIT compiler will treat it as an `invokespecial` call, basically a direct jump to the callee, or even inlining of the callee.

The above describes the optimization of the hardest case, a fully general virtual method. HotSpot also knows which methods are *effectively final*: in the set of loaded classes there is no occurrence of an override for that method. In that case HotSpot proceeds similar to above, but with a few instructions omitted (those which perform the type assertion).

I have additionally put some effort into hacking the .class file such that an `invokevirtual` instruction was replaced by `invokespecial`. The result was a `VerifyError`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: 
Bad invokespecial instruction: current class isn't assignable to reference class.
```

You can use `invokespecial` only for methods of the current class or its ancestor, and this is in fact [specified by the Java Virtual Machine Specification, §4.9.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9.2):

> Each `invokespecial` instruction must name an instance initialization method (§2.9), a method in the current class, or a method in a superclass of the current class.

Comment: Again, you are right about your addition, I just came to the same result. My instrumentation called its own type which is why the erroneous `INVOKESPECIAL` invocation for `final` methods worked by accident.

Answer (score 5):

`invokeinterface` is known to be slower than `invokevirtual`/`invokestatic`, especially when it comes to so-called "megamorphic calls": where a method has very many implementations, and the JIT-compiler has no way to optimize. So it's wise to prefer `invokevirtual` to `invokeinterface`. And the more specific the type you mention the more probably the optimistic optimizations (we consider this method final until a class that overrides it is loaded) will work.

Some more information is available here:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/invoke-interface-optimisations

Comment: Can you confirm the status of `invokespecial`? Is it allowed to be used against a regular virtual method? Or a non-private `final` method?

Comment: `invokespecial` can be used against a regular virtual method, as that is how you would invoke, e.g., `super.foo()` from `Bar`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel But that's a special case which can be checked. Can *any method of any class* be invoked with `invokespecial`?

Comment: @MikeStrobel Verification fails as soon as the `invokespecial`ed method is not in the current class (or its branch of hierarchy).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Interesting.  That conforms to the JVM spec, which I just double-checked: the operand must be an instance initializer, a private method, or an instance method in the superclass's hierarchy.  I was sure I had a test case where it was used to invoke an arbitrary method, but I must have been mistaken.  Also, the spec doesn't seem to cover non-private methods of the same class (as opposed to a superclass), though the verifier may let those slide.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Yes, I have just confirmed that as well. Any method, be it public or otherwise, of the current class may be invoked with `invokespecial`.